# Tab content(Google map) initialization problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to create Multiple dynamic Tabs with different google maps in each tabs.Also the the map should not initialize every time Tab clicks...My codings are below... Actually my problem is the Map initialized every time i click on Tabs...How to clear this issue...

//Function to create Tab dynamically

```
 function addTab(link,name) {
    $("#content").append("<div id='" + $(link).attr("value") +         "_content'style='width:100%;height:100%'></div>");
    var mid = $(link).attr("value")+"_content";

    tab1map(mid);

    $("#" + $(link).attr("value") + "_content").show();
}

//function for click event of Tabs

$('#tabs a.tab').live('click', function() {

    $("#content div").hide();

    $("#" + contentname).show();   // Here "contentname" is the id of the above Div tag when creating Tab
    tab1map(contentname);            //Here the Map function called again 
     // Here We should not call this map function again....the Map will Display with existing content in the $("#" + contentname).show(); itself..but it is not displayed....
 }             

// Map Function  
function tab1map(mid) {
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mid), myOptions);
}
```

Also I have tried google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); in click event of Tabs..But this also not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try and format your code in a nice manner as it helps people to read it and it would help if you could explain what is and what is not working. Thanks!

Comment: I dont think you're really providing enough info for anyone to help. You dont even explain what bit isn't working, but my guess would be that there elements with duplicate ID's in the DOM. Try to remove the hidden google map containers from the DOM completely, and only re-add them to the Tab just as its about to appear

Comment: Actually my problem is the Map initialized every time i click on Tabs...How to clear this issue